# What do you recommend for deploying web apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, web-applications

For deploying applications (Ruby apps, in my case) I've used [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/) and currently use [Vlad the Deployer](http://rubyhitsquad.com/Vlad_the_Deployer.html).

What do you use for deployment, and why?

Answer (score 1):

I use capistrano and subversion.

Capistrano is very well documented inline, and progressively better documented online.

see [The Absolute Moron's Guide to Capistrano](http://www.softiesonrails.com/2007/4/5/the-absolute-moron-s-guide-to-capistrano) (take no offence)

Takes a bit to get rolling, but then it's bless.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Subversion (source control) in the past to handle deployments to the web, and I know it has become more popular as time passes.  It makes it VERY easy to roll back if you have problems (on the code side).  Here's an article on it:

http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2005/04/linux-20050406.ars

Here's an article on setting it up on a more unix flavor:

http://www.jejik.com/articles/2008/08/easily_develop_and_deploy_web_applications_from_subversion/

For windows, I use the free VisualSVN bundle:

http://www.visualsvn.com/

and then just used the commandline tools to do the actual checkout.  I also found this previous question along the same lines (but for PHP):

[How to get started deploying PHP applications from a subversion repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800294/how-to-get-started-deploying-php-applications-from-a-subversion-repository)

Personally I don't like to have it fully automated - I still manually trigger the deployment and watch it, but some people may be comfortable letting the machine to things on its own.  :)